# Is it okay to indent to preserve 79 char limit?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a long line of code:

```
scores_pre = pd.Series([235.34, 928.23, 94.29, 943, 304, 405.45, 932.94, 823.45, 473.68, 382.48, 473.68, 382.48, 928.23, 94.29, 943, 304, 405.45])
```

To preserve a 79 char limit, I heard I should indent the line like this:

```
scores_pre = pd.Series([235.34, 928.23, 94.29, 943, 304, 405.45, 
                        823.45, 473.68, 382.48, 473.68, 382.48,
                        928.23, 94.29, 943, 304, 405.45])
```

However, given that indents in Python matter, I am worried this will have some side effect in my code. Is this type of indenting okay? Advisable?

(Forgive the noob question)

Comment: No no side effects, it is correct.

Comment: This is correct indentation and will not affect anything else.

Comment: 79 char limit is mainly for PEP8 convention and readability and its a kind of legacy from small size monitor from old age.

Comment: I am writing scripts mostly for myself (academic research... but the code is uploaded to github), if I don't mind long lines, should I just ignore it?

Comment: Yet, it's still good to have a line length limit in your coding standards though.  My company uses 120.

Comment: please check this post has some good explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903754/do-you-still-limit-line-length-in-code

Comment: more over once it converted into bytecode, char limit doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I don't see how this is mainly opinion based. Maybe the question should be reworded to put more weight on if it has any unintended effect on the code rather than if it is a good idea or not?

As it can be seen from Eric's answer, this question has an answer which is not: "almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts" ( sorry if this is the wrong place to comment on if this question should be on hold or not)

Answer (score 11):

From the docs, this is a perfectly legal thing to do:

> ## [Implicit line joining](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining)
>
> Expressions in parentheses, square brackets or curly braces can be
> split over more than one physical line without using backslashes. For
> example:
>
> ```
> month_names = ['Januari', 'Februari', 'Maart',      # These are the
>                'April',   'Mei',      'Juni',       # Dutch names
>                'Juli',    'Augustus', 'September',  # for the months
>                'Oktober', 'November', 'December']   # of the year
> ```
>
> Implicitly continued lines can carry comments. The indentation of the
> continuation lines is not important. Blank continuation lines are
> allowed. There is no NEWLINE token between implicit continuation
> lines. Implicitly continued lines can also occur within triple-quoted
> strings (see below); in that case they cannot carry comments.

Answer (score 4):

When you have an open parenthesis or bracket at the end of line, the indentation of the next lines (until the parentheses are closed) is ignored. So what you are doing is fine.